# nginx, www to non-ww, tried a dozen solutions

Tags: wordpress, web, nginx, vps

I have an small VPS hosting one wordpress website. I use ngingx 1.4.4 on Debian 12.04.
I follow some tutorials i found online and here is what i managed to make. 
Here is my server block:

```
server {
listen  80;
#listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires 365d;

}

root /var/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name bloggeri.es;

#Fix Yoast SEO Sitemaps
rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;  

# unless the request is for a valid file, send to bootstrap
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
#location /RequestDenied {
    # For example, return an error code
    #return 418;
#}

error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}

# Use gzip compression
gzip_static       on;  # Uncomment if you compiled Nginx using --with-http_gzip_static_module
gzip                on;
gzip_disable        "msie6";
gzip_vary           on;
gzip_proxied        any;
gzip_comp_level     5;
gzip_buffers        16 8k;
gzip_http_version   1.0;
gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/png image/gif image/jpeg;


# Set a variable to work around the lack of nested conditionals
set $cache_uri $request_uri;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $cache_uri 'no cache';
}   
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $cache_uri 'no cache';
}

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(\/wp-admin\/|\/xmlrpc.php|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|wp-.*\.php|index\.php|wp\-comments\-popup\.php|wp\-links\-opml\.php|wp\-locations\.php)") {
    set $cache_uri "no cache";
}

# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp\-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $cache_uri 'no cache';
}

# Cache static files for as long as possible
location ~* \.(xml|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    expires         max;
    access_log      off;
}

set $cache_uri $request_uri;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}   
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}   

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}   

# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}
```

}

Any one has a solutions?
I don`t know even if this is a good configuration

Comment: you should make your question more specific. What exactly is the problem you experience and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried everything i found on google, i`m new to nginx and this config i have i codes found after different searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to make a server block that matches the `www` url's and redirect them to a `non-www` url, add this above your server block after replacing `example.com` with your actual domain.

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
}
server {
  server_name example.com;
  # your actual config goes here
}
```

Comment: added that block but when i restart nginx i get a "fail" message.

Comment: what does the fail message say?, didn't it specify a message or a line number ?

Comment: i only "service nginx restart" and i just get a fail message (is red)

Comment: p.s. - i add that block above in the websitename config file, not in default (from sites-available)

Comment: are you the root user? if not you need to use `sudo`, also try running `sudo nginx -t` to test the configuration.
and yes you are supposed to add the new server inside the same virtual host file, more tidy that way.

Comment: is weird that now is working for other links beside homepage, on www.bloggeri.es i have the nginx page

Comment: @user1983344 did you get every thing fixed? or is there something missing? you said one site gives you nginx page?